# T-SQL: Can I make APPLY run a TVF on a CTE?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm compiling some documentation for work on stored procedures. I was able to create a query listing the tables and columns used by a stored procedure, but this is singular and requires me to pass the name of the stored procedure as an argument. I came across APPLY in the SQL documentation and it sounds like it could do what I want.

The code below seems halfway there; if you take the subquery for `t` and replace `n.name` with the name of any stored procedure, you'll get my desired output for **one** stored procedure.

```
with sprocnames as
(
select distinct name from sys.procedures
where name like '%sp%'
)
SELECT *
FROM sprocnames n outer apply
(
SELECT
      n.name as SprocName
    , referenced_id
    , referenced_entity_name AS table_name
    , referenced_minor_name as column_name
    , is_all_columns_found
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (n.name, 'OBJECT')
) as t
order by t.SprocName asc
```

The desired result would be a SELECT containing EVERY stored procedure on the server as well as a list of tables and columns used by each.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think that's possible. If I write a procedure, SELECT * FROM my_table, I don't think there is anywhere in the DB storing the procedure name along with my_table. Consider too if the procedure uses dynamic SQL. Then you're in trouble for sure.

Comment: @kjmerf you are correct about dynamic SQL procedures, but the database does store information about all it's objects, stored procedures included. In fact, if you run `SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(<ProcedureName>, 'P'))` (and replace `<ProcedureName>` with the name of a stored procedure, you'll get it's create script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. In fact, so close you will probably face-palm when you find out what your code is missing: The schema name.

The name you provide to `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` should be schema bound - i.e `dbo.procedureName`.

Here's a working version:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT s.name +'.'+ n.name As FullName
    FROM sys.procedures n
    JOIN sys.schemas s 
        ON n.schema_id = s.schema_id 
    WHERE s.name LIKE '%sp%'
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE 
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT
      CTE.FullName as SprocName
    , referenced_id
    , referenced_entity_name AS table_name
    , referenced_minor_name as column_name
    , is_all_columns_found
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (CTE.FullName, 'OBJECT')
) t
```

Please note, however, that this might also return errors. 
If fact, when I ran this on one of my databases, I've got the following error (as well as over 900 rows back):

> Msg 2020, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The dependencies reported for entity "dbo.sp_upgraddiagrams" might not include references to all columns. This is either because the entity references an object that does not exist or because of an error in one or more statements in the entity.  Before rerunning the query, ensure that there are no errors in the entity and that all objects referenced by the entity exist.

Which brings me to my final note: You should not use the `sp_` prefix for stored procedures. This prefix is reserved by Microsoft for built in procedures.
For more information, read Aaron Bertrand's [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)